# how do i send get from puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to send a get request with puppeteer, without having to use page.evaluate to use ajax. Is there a way to do this? I'm sure there is I've been scouring documentation but couldn't find any examples for this. I saw a thread on here about using post from puppeteer so I'm sure it's doable I'd just appreciate an example.

Comment: Why do you need the GET request to originate from puppeteer and not from any other library?

Comment: i mean i had pondered this and yeah youre probably correct, i just figured itd be more streamline if i kept it all as puppeteer.